# Neo4j expected Collection<T> but was Map when creating multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create multiple nodes in Neo4j using Cypher by passing properties as parameters as part of an `UNWIND` function, but I keep receiving the error `Type mismatch: expected Collection<T> but was Map`.

This happens even when using the following example from the Neo4j documentation ([link](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#create-create-multiple-nodes-with-a-parameter-for-their-properties)):

```
UNWIND {
  props : [ {
    name : "Andres",
    position : "Developer"
  }, {
    name : "Michael",
    position : "Developer"
  } ]
} AS map
CREATE (n)
SET n = map
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

*Note, the example above is not exactly as in the Neo4j documentation. Their example wraps the property names in double quotes, but this causes my instance of Neo4j to throw the error`Invalid input '"': expected whitespace...`)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UNWIND is expecting a collection, not a map as you're currently passing in, try this instead (just remove the wrapping curly braces and prop top level field):

```
UNWIND [ {
    name : "Andres",
    position : "Developer"
  }, {
    name : "Michael",
    position : "Developer"
  } ] AS map
CREATE (n)
SET n = map
```

Answer (score 3):

Chris's answer is of course the correct one, but here's why your solution doesn't work when you're following the documentation: you're *not* copying the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#create-create-multiple-nodes-with-a-parameter-for-their-properties).

The documentation shows the use of a named parameter:

```
UNWIND { props } AS map
CREATE (n)
SET n = map
```

with `props` passed in the map of parameters, which would look like:

```
{
  "props" : [ {
    "name" : "Andres",
    "position" : "Developer"
  }, {
    "name" : "Michael",
    "position" : "Developer"
  } ]
}
```

*if you displayed the map as JSON*. It means the `{props}` placeholder will be replaced by the *value* for the `props` key. Which is exactly what Chris did.

Here's what the Java code would look like:

```java
GraphDatabaseService db = /* init */;
Map<String, Object> andres = new HashMap<>();
andres.put("name", "Andres");
andres.put("position", "Developer");
Map<String, Object> michael = new HashMap<>();
michael.put("name", "Michael");
michael.put("position", "Developer");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("props", Arrays.asList(andres, michael));
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    db.execute("UNWIND {props} AS map CREATE (n) SET n = map", params);
    tx.success();
}
```